# Binance Smart Chain contract with withdraw and replenishment in both BUSD and USDT currencies

Tags: solidity, bsc

I have a task to make Solidity smart contract based on Binance Smart Chain network. That contract must withdraw and replenishment of funds with supporting both USDT and BUSD currences. But in contract must be one currency in circulation, without splitting on USDT or BUSD.

In other words, Users must replenish the balance (or withdraw his funds) with both USDT and BUSD. But in contract must appear one universal balance (no matter how you replenish the balance) with a rate 1 (usdt or busd) to 1 (universal coin, that circulate in the contract).

Please, tell me how to realize that feature? Is it possible in principle?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you making this contract? hat's your purpose, and what do you mean by circulation and withdrawal and replenishment ? your description is very ambiguous.

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime This is game, users must replenish the balance (or withdraw his funds) with both USDT and BUSD. But in contract must appear one universal balance (no matter how you replenish the balance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments :

> This is game, users must replenish the balance (or withdraw his funds) with both USDT and BUSD. But in contract must appear one universal balance (no matter how you replenish the balance)

In that case of a game, you should have a UI, right ? You can then show that the replenishment value is the sum of the BUSD and USDT tokens.

USDT and BUSD are tokens pegged to the value of the dollar, so in theory 1 BUSD = 1 USDT = 1$ (actual fiat dollar), If your game doesn't play on the inconsistency of both of those values where sometimes 1 USDT can be equal to 0.996$, the same for the BUSD, you can simply show the sum of those replenished tokens as dollars since both of those tokens will always try to get back to their value of 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I'm interesting technical scheme for that case. I understand correctly? I need to make the contract compatible with the ERC-20 standard. Then in the web interface and with metamask (for example), I must realize exchange for USDT and BUSD to my token/contract? Then I use my custom token value for inner calculations in the contract? Tell me please, either where I can show examples like that or where I can read about technical realizations like that? I'm interested only in solidity contract for binance smart chain, with web interface and web3 - I haven't problems.

Comment: Hello! Where are you?

Comment: @PeterIvanoff you are exchanging your token for to other tokens, so you can create your contract to be able to take those. for the value, USDT and BUSD are supposed to have the same value, so the user won't care if they have BUSD or USDT, unless they are into trading between them for low margins.

Comment: This link https://jeiwan.net/posts/programming-defi-uniswap-1/ is the most exemplary example of my task?